# ssh login asking for password and returning Permission denied Please try again

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssh, login, password

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and i am trying to `ssh` to another ubuntu 14.04 server which are on the same LAN. I am executing `ssh username@ip` its asking for password and upon typing the valid password its saying `Permission denied, please try again.` Both the systems do not have their home directory encrypted. Hoping anyone can guide me on this.

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server - Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

> I am executing `ssh username@ip`

Are you sure you have an user account `username` on the server `ip`? Even if user does not exist system will ask for password and response as you quoted.

If you have the user, after another `ssh username@ip` login attempt, please on the sshd server `ip` execute command `tail /var/log/auth.log`
and publish the output.